# Grouping repeated output strings in jq

Tags: json, bash, csv, group-by, jq

I am trying to convert JSON that looks like https://digitalcollections.ohsu.edu/api/items/11801 to a selective tab delimited format with a semicolon for a multivalue separator. I can select fields I want and get them in tab delimited format.

However, I still can't get multivalued fields to get concatenated into a single field with a semicolon separator without getting super kludgy. For example,

```
jq '.element_texts[] | (select(.element.name=="Title") | .text), (select(.element.name=="Subject") | .text)'
```

outputs fields I need. But I'm not able to convert the 3 subjects that get returned with this to a 3 item array that I can join -- I always get 3 separate strings. I can accomplish what I need by doing

```
jq '(.element_texts[] | (select(.element.name=="Title") | .text), (select(.element.name=="Date") | .text)), ([.element_texts[] | (select(.element.name=="Subject") | .text)] | join(";"))'
```

but I feel like there has to be a much simpler and better way but I can't see what it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the indicated input, the following filter produces the output as shown:

```
.element_texts
| [(.[]
   | ((select(.element.name=="Title"),
      (select(.element.name=="Date")))
   | .text)),
   (map(select(.element.name=="Subject") | .text) 
    | join(";") ) ]
| @tsv
```

### Output

```
Esther Pohl Lovejoy, M.D.   1894    Lovejoy, Esther Clayson Pohl, M.D., 1869-1967\r\n;Physicians, Women;Portraits
```